# Apache stalling Imagemagick Convert

Tags: python, apache, imagemagick

Ok, I know this sounds crazy, but bear with me...

I'm running an Ubuntu 16 cloud machine. A bunch of background processes happen that pull images, and do a handful of complex Imagemagick operations, then use FFMPEG to make videos of those images. And the process repeats for each image. Overall, it works very well, and is smooth. 
This server also houses a Flask App, that houses the front end of the result of this process.

However, from time to time, the Convert module just stalls. When viewing it in Top, the CPU usage goes down to 25% and just sits there. Images are not created, and it just sits there endlessly. If I kill the convert, and restart the image processes, the next image process stalls out. No error codes, it just sits there endlessly.

Overall it is pretty sparatic, BUT this is one way I can reproduce it, which is running the process with a very large image (10,000 pixels across).

The only way to get the process to 'reset' is to kill the convert, and restart Apache. Only after I restart Apache does the pipeline work again.

What the heck is going on? What does Apache have to do with Imagemagick?!

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you check var/log/syslog? There might be some useful information there. Is your system 4-core(25% could be one core running on full)? Also, add the convert command you are running.

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently running out of resources.  You can limit the amount of resources that "convert" will try to acquire either by

- the `-limit resource` option
  See http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit
- setting limits in a policy.xml file
  See http://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

I'd probably start by playing with the `-limit resource` option, then when I was happy with the results, write a policy.xml file containing default limits as a permanent solution until I got a larger machine that could deal with larger limits.

Comment: Ohhhh interesting. I am indeed on a low tier machine. Is there any way to confirm that that is indeed what the problem is?